# Creating Enum variable from a dynamic type that I know is an Enum?

Tags: c#, dynamic, types, enums

I hava a `System.Type type` variable which I checked `type.IsEnum` and it returned `true`.

Suppose that actually this `type` variable is `Direction` enum, which have these enumerations : `Left, Up, Down, Right` but the code earlier only know that it is an enum. It could be something else depends on `type` but we assured that it is an enum with `.IsEnum`

Now, how can I create a new variable of type `Direction` that this `type` represent? Say, I wanted its value to be from integer 0 which should represent `Left`.

Comment: Does Enum.ToObject give you what you need?

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. I think the method name is somewhat misleading because this method turns object to desired enum... Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please remember to drop a vote for comments you find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum.ToObject(Type,object)` solved this.

For example after I confirmed that `type` is a `System.Enum` then I can do `(System.Enum)Enum.ToObject(type,0)`.

It's confusing because despite the name `Enum.ToObject`, this method convert object to enum not enum to object. But maybe the name is referring to returned type of this method which is `object`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the enum you got is of the `Direction` type, and subsequently do something with it, you can check that using the `IsAssignableFrom` method on a type, like in the example below:

```
enum Direction
{
    Left = 0,
    Up,
    Down,
    Right
}

public static void DoSomethingIfDirection(object item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        Type type = item.GetType();
        if (type.IsEnum && typeof(Direction).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            // Do something
            Console.WriteLine((Direction)item);
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    DoSomethingIfDirection("Hello");
    DoSomethingIfDirection("Left");
    DoSomethingIfDirection(Direction.Left);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but `Direction` is only an example. In actual application I wanted it to work with any Enum type that `type` variable carries.